# error while loading shared libraries: libopenpose.so.1.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openpose

I'm using Google Colab to Pose estimation with Openpose; I've mounted my gdrive, installed openpose and copied it's directory on a drive one.
It was all working until after I closed and reopened my session after few hours
After compiling this cell on the notebook :
`

```
video_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/datasetRaw/prova1.mp4"
video_height = 480
output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/datasetRaw/json_frames/"
video_output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/datasetRaw/json_keys/prova1-sk.mp4"

!./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin \
--model_pose BODY_25B \
--video {video_path} \
--write_json {output_path} --display 0 \
--number_people_max 1 \
--write_video {video_output_path}
```

this happens :

```
./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libopenpose.so.1.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

Can anyone helps me solving this? Thanks in advance
I'm starting to think that this issue it's related to the runtime, I'm on a CPU runtime cause my GPU limit usage by Colab, but I'm not sure about this.

It's a new error, before of this it showed to me that I hadn't the permission to write openpose.bin file inside the ./build/examples/openpose/ folder and I solved this by changing the permission. I don't think can be caused by a bad installation cause yesterday it was working well.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but I was confronted with the same problem and solved it.

I'm pretty sure you copied the openpose folder instead of moving it.
While the environment was on, OpenPose could still find its libraries where it was searching them.

But then, when you disconnected from Colab, the default folder was removed and the libraries were not there anymore.

One quick and dirty way to solve it is to find the libraries and move them to a "normal" path, such as `/usr/local/lib`.

```
!cp path_to_openpose/build/src/openpose/libopenpose.so.1.7.0 /usr/local/lib
!cp path_to_openpose/build/caffe/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib
!sudo ldconfig
```

You also need to reinstall all the libraries needed by OpenPose:

```
!apt-get -qq install -y libatlas-base-dev libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev opencl-headers ocl-icd-opencl-dev libviennacl-dev
```